# resonanting frequency phase

Tags: frequency, resonance, phase-diagram

I know phase at resonating frequency is Zero!! Now the question is, can anyone help me to prove it. I was looking for a better clarification with diagrams that can help me grasp the concept.

Comment: Totally unclear what you're asking. Please elaborate/provide context.

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when one has two coupled systems, one will do work on the other if it is
out of phase.   So, if systems that are so coupled are not being forced,
i.e. if one is NOT doing work on the other, they are in phase.   If
they STAY in phase, it is because they are at their natural resonance
(because, by hypothesis, there is no external forcing...).

Trios of piano strings are never exactly resonant at the same
frequency, so the energy stored in each will wax and wane as it
is driven by (or drives) the neighboring strings.

A common lab test for electrical resonance (driving an RLC circuit
from a loosely-coupled signal generator) is, to a good approximation,
'at resonance' of the driven circuit when the phase of the generator
voltage is the same as the RLC response voltage.   Below resonant
frequency, the response is inductor-like (resistive generator driving
inductor, the inductor terminal voltage leads the generator in phase),
and above resonant frequency, the response is capacitor-like (capacitor
terminal voltage lags the generator in phase).   It's in-phase
at resonance.